# tmux with C-shell (tcsh) alias are lost

Tags: shell, alias, tmux, tcsh

I am running tmux (version 1.9a) on a Mac OS X 10.6.8 with iTerm 2.

My default shell is tcsh, and I have several alias (and path, environment variables) defined in my .tcshrc file.

The problem is that all the alias are not defined when I run tmux, although I set tmux to run with the tcsh shell by default.

**Addition:** On the other hand the environment variables set in my .tcshrc are correctly passed in tmux. It seems a problem related just to alias...

Below my .tmux.conf

```
# copy and paster
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l tcsh"

# Define the default shell
set-option -g default-shell /bin/tcsh

# Avoid problems with alias defined in .tcshrc
set-option -g default-command $SHELL

set-option -g default-command "source .tcshrc"

# look good
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

set -g prefix C-a
unbind C-b
bind C-a send-prefix

# a mouse
set -g mode-mouse on
setw -g mouse-select-window on
setw -g mouse-select-pane on

# # Scroll History
set -g history-limit 30000

# Count sessions start at 1
set -g base-index 1

# act like vim
setw -g mode-keys vi
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R
bind-key -r C-h select-window -t :-
bind-key -r C-l select-window -t :+
unbind [
bind -t vi-copy v begin-selection
bind -t vi-copy y copy-selection

# after copying to a tmux buffer, hit y again to copy to clipboard
bind y run "tmux save-buffer - | reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"

bind N swap-window -t +1
bind P swap-window -t -1

# Reload .tmux.conf
#bind R source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "  Config reloaded.."

# Hit [PREFIX]-R to reorder windows (i..e from 1-4-7-9 to 1-2-3-4 keeping the right order)
bind R                                      \
    set -g renumber-windows on\;            \
    new-window\; kill-window\;              \
    set -g renumber-windows off\;           \
    display-message "Windows reordered..."

# Rename your terminals
set -g set-titles on
set -g set-titles-string '#(whoami)::#h::#(curl ipecho.net/plain;echo)'



# Status bar customization
# Set status bar
set -g status-justify left
set -g status-bg black
set -g status-fg white
set-option -g status-interval 5
set -g status-right-length 150
set -g status-left ""
set -g status-right "#[fg=green] %m-%d-%Y %H:%M #(whoami)@minimul.com             " # Add space so I can see Growl notifications in full-screen mode

# Rather than constraining window size to the maximum size of any client 
# connected to the *session*, constrain window size to the maximum size of any 
# client connected to *that window*. Much more reasonable.
setw -g aggressive-resize on

# Allows us to use '<prefix>-a' <command> to send commands to a TMUX session inside 
# another TMUX session
bind-key a send-prefix

# Highlight active window
set-window-option -g window-status-current-bg red
```

Comment: Why do you configure tmux to run tcsh if that's already your default shell you've set in `/etc/passwd`, with `chsh`? That shouldn't be necessary...

Comment: Correct, but that was an addition I put to try solving the problem of alias...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the issue was solved by keeping the line

```
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l tcsh"
```

while erasing the lines

```
# Define the default shell
set-option -g default-shell /bin/tcsh

# Avoid problems with alias defined in .tcshrc
set-option -g default-command $SHELL

set-option -g default-command "source .tcshrc"
```

And restarting iTerm2 (no source or rehash did the job).

Answer (score 0):

This would be because when you launch a standard shell from the terminal, it's a login shell, but with the option you've set for tmux, it's just an additional shell.

This line:

```
set-option -g default-command $SHELL
```

actually causes it to launch as a non-login shell. You've probably got some code blocked off with:

```
if($?loginsh) then
    ...
endif
```

which means that it doesn't get invoked in that case.

If you change the option to:

```
set-option -g default-command "$SHELL -l"
```

It will act like a login shell; alternatively remove the `default-command`, and in that case it will invoke the default shell as a login shell, which should have the same effect.

As an attempt at debugging this I started with a from-scratch `.tcshrc` containing:

```
echo tcshrc
if($?loginsh) then
    echo login
endif
if($?prompt) then
    echo prompt
endif
```

with `set-option -g default-command ""` (the default) I saw:

```
tcshrc
login
prompt
```

with `set-option -g default-command "$SHELL"` I see:

```
tcshrc
tcshrc
prompt
```

with `set-option -g default-command "$SHELL -l"` I see:

```
tcshrc
tcshrc
login
prompt
```

with `set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace tcsh"` I see:

```
tcshrc
tcshrc
prompt
```

with `set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l tcsh"` I see:

```
tcshrc
tcshrc
login
prompt
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, but I tried both alternatives, adding `set-option -g default-command "$SHELL -l"` and removing the line `set-option -g default-command $SHELL`, and neither work...
Could you try on your station? i.e. creating some alias in .tcshrc and running tmux with the tcsh shell?

Comment: All aliases put into my `.tcshrc` work when unguarded. When I put them into an `if($?loginsh) then` they appear when I use `set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-session -l tcsh"`. If I omit the `-l`, then they still appear in a `if($?prompt) then` block. You *must* have some `if...then` condition preventing the aliases from being loaded.

Comment: The easiest way of debugging this is `echo` debugging. Use them to determine the code path when it encounters conditional sections.

Comment: Where this `if...then` block should be? In my .tcshrc? Since if I just put the following line in my .tcshrc `alias cdlib 'cd ~/lib'` it still doesn't work in tmux...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Petesh! I guess I have some more serious issue here, since if I put your suggested code into my .tcshrc I get 

`tcshrc` (then on a newline)

`then: then/endif not found.`

Comment: my bad, that should have been `if... endif`, not `if... fi` (bash scripting)

Comment: Ok, so now I do get (each one on a newline) `tcshrc` `login` `prompt`, how do I interpret this?

Comment: The echoes indicate that you're getting a login shell in tmux. I'm at a loss as to why it's not making your aliases available as all the aliases I've defined in my `.tcshrc` file appear when I invoke the `alias` command once within tmux.